# Convert a time (represented by a string) from one timezone to another

Tags: c, datetime, timezone

In my app, I convert user-specified time into `time_t` format and store it. At a later point, I display this time in local time zone. Here is my test code:

```
int main() {
  const char* INPUTFMT =  "%b %d, %Y %H:%M:%S %Z";
  const char* SAMPLETIME = "Feb 19, 2016 01:00:00 EST";

  struct tm tm = {0};
  char* val = strptime(SAMPLETIME, INPUTFMT, &tm);

  time_t st = mktime(&tm);

  const struct tm* t1 = localtime(&st);
  static const char* OUTPUTFMT = "%b %d, %G %I:%M:%S %p %Z";
  char buf[100];
  strftime (buf, 100, OUTPUTFMT, t1);

  printf("%s\n", buf);

  return 0;
}
```

The specified timezone is EST and my local timezone is PST.

The problem I am running into is that, although my local timezone is different than the one specified, I see the same time except that EST is replaced by PST.

I am wondering what is it that I am doing wrong. Regards.

Comment: @stackptr Even when the semantic meaning is a CONSTANT?

Comment: Pretty sure all caps is the standard for c/c++ const naming.

Comment: C does not have symbolic constants. It is not C++. `const` qualified objects are **semantically** still variables. Use macros instead.

Comment: @Olaf Semantic, as in "relating to [the] meaning [of]"?

Comment: @user2864740: Just stick to the **language semantics**. In C, either use _enum-constants_ (true symbolic constant, but always `int` and syntactically problematic) or a macro - the common way. C is not C++, thus you should not try to code C++ style in C (and vice versa). And the pointers are **not** `const` anyway!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The man-page for `strptime` on my system (OS X) says:

> The %Z format specifier only accepts time zone abbreviations of the
>   local time zone, or the value "GMT".  This limitation is because of
>   ambiguity due to of the over loading of time zone abbreviations.  One
>   such example is EST which is both Eastern Standard Time and Eastern
>   Australia Summer Time.

Thus this line:

```
char* val = strptime(SAMPLETIME, INPUTFMT, &tm);
```

is silently ignoring the "EST" in the input and instead using your current local time offset instead.  And thus when you convert it back from your current local time here:

```
strftime (buf, 100, OUTPUTFMT, t1);
```

You get a round-trip from your current local time to UTC and back to your current local time.

See this *language-neutral* [stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2532962/576911) for more advice on how to handle timezones.